# Copy selected/checked checkbox values and display them in a different form/div as text

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, jstl

I am populating a div with checkboxes whose value fields are copied from a dynamic array. The div looks like this:

```
<div id="services" class="servicefilterDiv">
    <div class="card-header">Services</div>
        <div class="ServiceBox">
            <c:forEach var="svcLookUp" items="${svclookups}">
                <div class="serviceListDiv">
                    <div class="child_div_1">
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                         id="serviceCheckBox${svcLookUp.serviceCode}" 
                         value="${svcLookUp.serviceCode}">
                         <c:out value="${svcLookUp.serviceCode}" />
                         -
                         <c:out value="${svcLookUp.service}" />
                        </input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have another div with id as displayServices, where I basically need to create as many rows as the checkboxes that were checked and display the selected/checked checkbox values in each of these rows. I'm trying to go for a final presentation which sort of looks like this:

[copiedElements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06MRq.png)

I have created one div where all the 4 fields (2 headers, 1 button and 1 text value for service) are present and am using ul and li tags to achieve this sort of presentation. Now, I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to have just one div for this (like I have), and populate every selected checkbox value similar to recursion
2. Secondly, how do I pass those checkbox values into the other div?

Is there a better approach for doing this? How do I pass the values from the checked checkboxes to one of these li tags?

Comment: Depending on your other requirements, one option might be to create the other div prepopulated with all the data for all the services, and simply toggle show/hide as the checkboxes are clicked - something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997905/show-div-based-on-selected-checkboxes

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's another way I could approach this. However, I am concerned that making the function call again to pre-populate the data might lead to performance issues in the future. Wish there was a way to just copy them over, I'll look at that. Thank you so much.

Comment: IF (big "if" :) )all that the second div is to contain is what is already in (or can be made to be in) `svclookups`, then there's no added overhead (so far faster than making ajax calls when clicking the checkboxes, for example).

Comment: oh, didn't know that. I thought it would make a call again, so there would be overheads. Thank you so much!